# Load ASP.NET MVC views and controllers code from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, virtualpathprovider

I have a system in which the end-user is a developer who can create ASP.NET MVC views/controllers and run them on the fly.

Currently, I have two database tables, one to store the view name and code and other to store controller code in C#. I can compile the build an assembly and save a dll file on the server folder.

**Step 1**: I added a **custom controller factory** to load my controller from the database, having an area in the project named (**QZone**).

```
public class QS_DynamicControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory//, IController
{
    QS_DBConnection _db = new QS_DBConnection();
    public QS_DynamicControllerFactory() { }
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        return (requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] != null && 
                requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString().ToLower() == "qzone") ?
            QGetControllerInstance(controllerName) : base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
    }
    internal IController QGetControllerInstance(string controllerName)
    {
        //load controller from the database and compile it then return an instance
    }
    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        base.ReleaseController(controller);
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: I created a **VirtualPathProvider, VirtualFile**

`QS_VirtualPathProvider` class:

```
public class QS_VirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{
    public QDynamicView GetVirtualData(string viewPath)
    {
        QS_DBConnection _db = new QS_DBConnection();
        QDynamicView view = (from v in _db.QDynamicViews
                             where v.Name.ToLower() == "TestView.cshtml".ToLower()//viewPath.ToLower()
                             select v).SingleOrDefault();
        return view;
    }
    private bool IsPathVirtual(string virtualPath)
    {
        var path = (VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(virtualPath) != "~/") ? VirtualPathUtility.RemoveTrailingSlash(VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(virtualPath)) : VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(virtualPath);
        if (path.ToLower().Contains("/qzone/"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (IsPathVirtual(virtualPath))
        {
            QS_VirtualFile file = (QS_VirtualFile)GetFile(virtualPath);
            bool isExists = file.Exists;
            return isExists;
        }
        else
            return Previous.FileExists(virtualPath);
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (IsPathVirtual(virtualPath))
        {
            QDynamicView vw = GetVirtualData(virtualPath);
            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vw.ViewCode);
            return new QS_VirtualFile(virtualPath, bytes);
        }
        else
            return Previous.GetFile(virtualPath);
    }

    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        if (IsPathVirtual(virtualPath))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
            return Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
    }

    public override string GetFileHash(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies)
    {
        if (IsPathVirtual(virtualPath))
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        return base.GetFileHash(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies);
    }
}
```

`QS_VirtualFile` class:

```
public class QS_VirtualFile : VirtualFile
{
    private string content;
    private QS_VirtualPathProvider spp;

    public bool Exists
    {
        get { return (content != null); }
    }
    public QS_VirtualFile(string virtualPath, QS_VirtualPathProvider provider) : base(virtualPath)
    {
        this.spp = provider;
        GetData(virtualPath);
    }

    public QS_VirtualFile(QDynamicView vw, string virtualPath) : base(virtualPath)
    {
        content = vw.ViewCode;
    }

    private byte[] _BinaryContent;

    public QS_VirtualFile(string virtualPath, byte[] contents) : base(virtualPath)
    {
        this._BinaryContent = contents;
    }

    protected void GetData(string virtualPath)
    {
        QDynamicView QSView = spp.GetVirtualData(virtualPath);

        if (QSView != null)
        {
            content = QSView.ViewCode;
        }
    }

    public override Stream Open()
    {
        return new MemoryStream(_BinaryContent);
    }
}
```

**Step 3**: register the controller factory and the virtual path provider in the in `Global.asax`** file:

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new QS_VirtualPathProvider());
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new QS_DynamicControllerFactory());
```

testing the code
in order to test the code above i added a controller named (test) and a view named (testView.cshtml) in the database and requested the url below:

> http://localhost:1001/qzone/test/TestView

and I got this error

[image]

I guess this mean that the controller factory worked fine but the view was not loaded

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's looking for your view on the hard drive. The View Engine uses `VirtualPathProviders`to resolve your views, so you need to write your own `VirtualPathProvider` and register it.

You can find the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider?view=netframework-4.8

Unfortunately, it is way too much code for me to copy here, but you can find a full example there.
Mind you, the example is for .NET 4.8, so if you're using Core, this may not be applicable.

Comment: this is what i did, i created mt own VirtualPathProvider. it is shown in the question QS_VirtualPathProvider and it is also registered. furthermore, i followed the MSDN sample.

Comment: Can you verify that your virtual path provider is called by putting a breakpoint in your code?

Comment: it is called and also the controller factory is called, but as far as i can see the (FileExists) method is being called over and over even if the file is found

Comment: Okay, and is the variable content filled correctly? So that Exists is definitely true?

Comment: i tried both methods, one to return true it gives 404 error and to return false gives the error in the question above